# How to handle HTTP status errors with React Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a simple login application made with apollo-server-express in the backend. If the user enters an invalid username or password it throws a 401 Unauthorized exception like this:

```
async login(username: string, password: string) {
     const user = await this.userService.findOneByUsername(username);
     if (!user) {
         throw new UnauthorizedException("The username doesn't exists");
     }
     const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
     if (!validPassword) {
         throw new UnauthorizedException('The password is incorrect');
     }
     return user;
}
```

Now, in my React client, I use Apollo Client to consume the service. I have made my login like this:

```
const [login, { error, loading }] = useLoginMutation({
  variables: {
    username,
    password,
  },
});

const onFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const response = await login();
  if (response) {
    if (response.data) {
      localStorage.setItem("user", response.data.login.jwt);
      addUser(response.data.login.user);
    }
  }
};
```

Now, when I enter a bad username or password, the exception is thrown in the backend, but it makes the React app stop. This is solved by adding a catch statement after the login() method like this:

```
const response = await login().catch(e => { });
```

But I want to know if there is a gracefully way to either catch the exception in the client or throwing it in the server. In REST services errors like 401 don't make the app stop, the request only fails but the app still running, but I'm new with GraphQL and I want to know if is not like this in GraphQL services.
Is there a better way to handle or thrown Http errors with GraphQL and Apollo?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking when you say “gracefully way to either catch the exception in the client or throwing it in the server.”

Comment: @rayhatfield I want to know the better way to either handle an HTTP exception in the client, in this case, a React app with Apollo Client, or to throw them in the Server, in this case, a NestJs app using apollo-server-express

Comment: You could wrap the `await login` stuff in a try/catch, or move the whole thing into a custom useLogin hook that handles it so individual components don’t have to deal with it, but I’m still not sure I understand what you’re asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The Problem

`async/await` statement must be in a `try/catch` block. more on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) documentation.

`then/catch` is another way to handle async promises but the result is the same as `async/await`, so don't mix them together.

##### The Solution

with current implementation (`async/await`) you need to wrap the async fetch function in a `try/catch` block to control all the side effects (success and failure scenario).

```
const onFormSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const response = await login();
    if (response?.data) {
        localStorage.setItem("user", response.data.login.jwt);
        addUser(response.data.login.user);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // do a proper action in error cases
    const myErrorStatus = error.response?.status
    if(myErrorStatus === 401) {
      // do this
    } else if (myErrorStatus === 404) {
      // do this
    } 
  }
};
```

##### Optionally:

**Note:** instead of using nested `if` block for checking the `response`, you could use the `?` shorthand. for example:

```
if(a){
  if(a.b){
    if(a.b.c){
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
if(a?.b?.c){
 // ...
}
```